# How do I change the name of the button and save it when reloading the page with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a page with a button that when I click on it it changes but if I reload the page it returns as it is without changing
html

```
<button onload="form1.reset();" class="button" id="movetool10" onclick="movetool10();stoptool10()">حجز</button>
```

javascript

```
var clickCounter10 = 0;
var movetool10 = document.getElementById('movetool10')
movetool10.onclick = function() {
clickCounter10++;
if (clickCounter10 ===2) {
clickCounter10 = 0;
document.getElementById('movetool10').innerHTML = 'click !';
}
else {
document.getElementById('movetool10').innerHTML = 'click me';
}
};
```

Comment: If you have a backend app, you can pass the value from the server or you can save the button text to storage and read it from there.

Comment: Okay, could you write the code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of localStorage, save the last counter value there and fetch it in the begining, if it exists, use it. Otherwise, initialize the counter with 0 for first time render (or someone clears the localStorage). Please note that this is only on client side, so if the user clears the localStorage, the counter will be reinitialised.

Right now, the button shows up from its last state. It is toggling between the two states, you can change the logic however you want, but this is how you can make use of localStorage.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8d46ukhq/24/)

```
var clickCounter10 = window.localStorage.getItem('clickCounter10') || 0;
var movetool10 = document.getElementById('movetool10');

changeBtn();
movetool10.onclick = function() {
  clickCounter10++;
  window.localStorage.setItem('clickCounter10', clickCounter10);
  changeBtn();
};

function changeBtn() {
  clickCounter10 = parseInt(clickCounter10, 10);
  if (clickCounter10 === 2) {
    clickCounter10 = 0;
    document.getElementById('movetool10').innerHTML = 'click !';
  } else if(clickCounter10 !== 0) {
    document.getElementById('movetool10').innerHTML = 'click me';
  }
}
```